# Xamarin.Forms: default instead of AndroidClientHandler as HttpClient implementation

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, httpclient, httpclienthandler

I work on an existing **Xamarin.Forms app**, where we need to integrate **API calls** to external providers.

For this, we use my **client's custom HttpClient library**.

Until now, the **Android HttpClient** was set to `AndroidClientHandler`.

But after a basic call to a provider's API, we get a "**400 - bad request**" answer:

```
HttpContent content = new StringContent(string.Empty);
if (tObject != null)
{
    string data = JsonSerializer.Serialize(tObject, new JsonSerializerOptions() { IgnoreNullValues = true, IgnoreReadOnlyProperties = true });

    content = new StringContent(data, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
}
HttpResponseMessage apiResponse = await _client.PostAsync(route, content);
string responseData = await apiResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

If we set the **Android HttpClient** to `default`, all works fine.

***But it seems that it's better choice to use the AndroidClientHandler.
So would you have suggestions to investigate and identify the issue related to the AndroidClientHandler?***

Comment: use wireshark or another tool to examine the different requests and figure out what is triggering the 400

Comment: I've tried this with Charles Proxy, but I wasn't able to decode the requests. I will try with wireshark to compare.

Comment: Install the Charles root cert on your device if you want to decode the contents of your requests if they are over SSL.